# Parabola for free fall, tangent to v vector

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have picture,

[image]

Please help me draw parabola from point A tangent to V0.

[image]

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw  (0,3) -- (3,3)-- node[left] {H} (3,2) -- node[below] {$L_{max}$} (6,2);
 \draw [dashed]   (3,3) -- +(0:1.5);
 \draw [->] [>=stealth,line width=0.3mm]   (3,3) -- +(30:1.5) node [near end, above] {${\vec{v}}_0$};
\draw (4,3) arc (0:30:1) node at (38:5.3) {$\alpha$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an approximation you could use something like

```
\draw [red,thick,dashed] (3,3) to[out=30,in=100] (5.5,2);
```

`in=100` means that the path hits its endpoint from the direction 100 degrees. Adjust that to your preference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw  (0,3) -- (3,3)-- node[left] {H} (3,2) -- node[below] {$L_{\mathrm{max}}$} (6,2);
 \draw [dashed]   (3,3) -- +(0:1.5);
 \draw [->,>=stealth,line width=0.3mm]   (3,3) -- +(30:1.5) node [near end, above] {${\vec{v}}_0$};
 \draw (4,3) arc (0:30:1) node at (38:5.3) {$\alpha$};
 \draw [red,thick,dashed] (3,3) to[out=30,in=100] (5.5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or if you like, you can figure out the time when the parabola hits the lower plane, and plot that. If I remember this correctly:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \newcommand\initialV{4} % initial speed
 \newcommand\launchangle{30} % angle of launch
 \newcommand\gravity{9.81} % force of gravity

 % the lower plane is one unit below the exit, so set y = t*v_0*sin(theta) - 0.5*g*t^2 = -1, and solve for t
 \pgfmathsetmacro\timeofimpact{\initialV*sin(\launchangle)/\gravity + sqrt((\initialV*sin(\launchangle)/\gravity)^2 + 2/\gravity)}
 \draw  (0,3) -- (3,3)-- node[left] {H} (3,2) -- node[below] {$L_{\mathrm{max}}$} (6,2);
 \draw [dashed]   (3,3) -- +(0:1.5);
 \draw [->,>=stealth,line width=0.3mm]   (3,3) -- +(\launchangle:1.5) node [near end, above] {${\vec{v}}_0$};
 \draw (4,3) arc (0:30:1) node at (38:5.3) {$\alpha$};
 % domain based on calculation above
 \draw [red,thick,dashed,variable=\t,domain=0:\timeofimpact] (3,3) plot ({3+\t*\initialV*cos(\launchangle)},{3+\t*\initialV*sin(\launchangle) - 0.5*\gravity*\t^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]